# How do I configure the cache size for Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mmap

I need to handle cashing in Mongodb.Does It requires a lot of RAM for doing that? 
What are the specialties and advantages using storage engines in this case?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming based questions, which this is not. This is related to database configuration and should instead be posted on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: ok removing the question there, should i delete it ? @BlakesSeven

Answer (score 8):

1. Method (does not survive a restart):

   ./bin/mongo admin

   > db.adminCommand( { "setParameter": 1, "wiredTigerEngineRuntimeConfig": "cache_size=10G"})
2. start mongodb serve with

   ./bin/mongod --config server.conf --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=10

--- server.conf (one key/value per line) ---

```
maxConns=200
logpath=logs/server.log
logappend=true
fork=true
dbpath=data
nohttpinterface=true
syncdelay=60
quiet = true
slowms = 2000
notablescan = false
```

Check size with this command:

```
> db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache
{
        "bytes currently in the cache" : 4606522365,
        "bytes read into cache" : 3291056,
        "bytes written from cache" : 5631783282,
        "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
        "eviction currently operating in aggressive mode" : 0,
        "eviction server candidate queue empty when topping up" : 448,
        "eviction server candidate queue not empty when topping up" : 0,
        "eviction server evicting pages" : 0,
        "eviction server populating queue, but not evicting pages" : 447,
        "eviction server unable to reach eviction goal" : 0,
        "eviction worker thread evicting pages" : 12,
        "failed eviction of pages that exceeded the in-memory maximum" : 0,
        "files with active eviction walks" : 0,
        "files with new eviction walks started" : 105,
        "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 0,
        "in-memory page passed criteria to be split" : 896,
        "in-memory page splits" : 448,
        "internal pages evicted" : 0,
        "internal pages split during eviction" : 0,
        "leaf pages split during eviction" : 13,
        "lookaside table insert calls" : 0,
        "lookaside table remove calls" : 0,
        "maximum bytes configured" : 10737418240,  <---- this is the configured size
        "maximum page size at eviction" : 8388576,
        "modified pages evicted" : 13,
        "modified pages evicted by application threads" : 0,
        "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
        "page written requiring lookaside records" : 0,
        "pages currently held in the cache" : 675,
        "pages evicted because they exceeded the in-memory maximum" : 1,
        "pages evicted because they had chains of deleted items" : 448,
        "pages evicted by application threads" : 0,
        "pages queued for eviction" : 12,
        "pages queued for urgent eviction" : 0,
        "pages read into cache" : 234,
        "pages read into cache requiring lookaside entries" : 0,
        "pages seen by eviction walk" : 25702,
        "pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 0,
        "pages walked for eviction" : 127975,
        "pages written from cache" : 310352,
        "pages written requiring in-memory restoration" : 0,
        "percentage overhead" : 8,
        "tracked bytes belonging to internal pages in the cache" : 316858,
        "tracked bytes belonging to leaf pages in the cache" : 4606205507,
        "tracked bytes belonging to overflow pages in the cache" : 0,
        "tracked dirty bytes in the cache" : 809239633,
        "tracked dirty pages in the cache" : 190,
        "unmodified pages evicted" : 0
}
```

Comment: the command works, but it doesn't reduce the previous memory footprint, is there a clear cache command that has to be run to purge the current in-use to bring it down to the new level?

Answer (score 5):

A more concise output of the WT cache size in GB would be :

db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache["maximum bytes configured"]/1024/1024/1024
64

Answer (score 0):

Dba is the appropriate place. Caching is already defined if you are using WiredTiger, using all RAM available, with dynamic provisioning.

Comment: Little bit explanation or reference is welcomed @Ricardo

Comment: It's a mongod setup, while raising up the server. A tip is here ( on the topic of cache): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/ . If you're not familiar with WiredTiger I strongly recommend you to read their documentation.

Comment: What  about MMAPV1 ? I am familiar with that.how can i configure cashing with that? @Ricardo

Comment: @IstiakMorsalin MMAPV1 is probably turning to a legacy system soon. On their [website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/) they point to this, and specially considering that they bought the company (WiredTiger).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I got the answer. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251029/mongodb-fills-the-server-memory-after-a-while/).

I hope your problem is solved too.

Summary answer :)

You need to add these configurations to docker-campus configurations:

```
.......
        deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: 3G
            reservations:
              memory: 1G
    command: --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 0.25
    
.......
```