# Mongodb fills the server memory after a while

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, pymongo, gunicorn

I wrote the Python program using flask, which reads some data from MongoDB. But after a few hours of running the program on server , it starts to fill up server memory by MongoDB until all the server memory is used.

[Status of server resources when running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flg6l.png)

After a few hours, the state of server resources is as follows

[Status of server resources after a few hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHF3K.png)

#### The technologies I have used

1. MongoDB on docker
2. python 3.8
3. Flask 2.0.2
4. pymongo 4.0.1
5. gunicorn 20.1.0

#### Docker file

```
FROM python:3.8.7-buster
WORKDIR /flask_app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ENV FLASK_APP=server.py
CMD ["gunicorn", "server:app", "-w", "2","--log-level" ,"DEBUG", "--threads", "2", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Comment: Please have a look here on How to properly ask a question. Might help you get the answer quickly - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have the same kind of problem with some apps running with mongodb, I believe this is related to cache usage. By default mongodb is not supposed to use more than 50% of the available RAM but you can also configure this explicitely, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889947/how-do-i-configure-the-cache-size-for-mongodb .
Also, you can clean the system cache once in a while running `sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` (as root)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this problem is due to the MongoDB cache system.

And to solve this problem, you have to limit the amount of RAM consumption for MongoDB.

This does not reduce MongoDB **performance** and does not have much effect on it, but it does solve the problem.

You need to add these configurations to docker-campus configurations:

```
.......
        deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: 3G
            reservations:
              memory: 1G
    command: --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 0.25
    
.......
```

In this case, the consumption of MongoDB memory is fixed at **5.2**, you can adjust your consumption.

Good luck :)